# Attribute Error while runserver command on Django Site

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, server

Any help would greatly be appreciated

The browser gives me this error:

```
AttributeError at /blog/
type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    htp://mysite.com/blog/ (spelling errror on purpose)
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'
Exception Location: /root/mysite/blog/views.py in post_list, line 4
Python Executable:  /root/my_env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
    ['/root/mysite',
     '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
     '/usr/lib/python3.6',
     '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
     '/root/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
     Server time:   Tue, 30 Jun 2020 21:31:42 +0000
```

The server gives me this error

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /blog/

```
entTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in 
 _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/root/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in 
_get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/root/mysite/blog/views.py", line 4, in post_list
 posts = Post.published.all()
 AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'publisheder code here
```

I hate when I buy digital books (even the ones with good reviews or by established companies) and they don't work out well I got this from a sample of the django3 book by A. Mele. It would be nice if they gave you insight into the error you can get.

Comment: I can provide the model or views file im sure that where the error is ocurring thanks again for helping!

Comment: Looks like the attribute published is missing from your model. Please post your view and model. Did you also apply all migrations?

Comment: I have omitted some lines but here is my models.py
from .models import Post 
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render    (request,'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})
    
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
       status='published',
       publish__year=year,
       publish__month=month,
       pubish__day=day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post': post})

Comment: Im sorry about the bad syntax im new to posting on SO here is my views.py


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render    (request,'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})
    
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
       status='published',

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all Posts you should be doing the following

```
Post.objects.all()
```

Otherwise, you should post more information about the problem (what is the objective, what did you do, and when does it fails) post the code you are having trouble with

Comment: Thanks Diego! I am trying to post the "published posts" you can see the source code for the assignment on git hub. at https://github.com/guinslym/django-by-example-book/tree/master/chap_1_blog/mysite/blog
the url is supposed to be localhost/blog/ and also I sort of thought that it was because of mispelling or syntax im just at the point where I can not evaluate what im reading so I gave up an threw the error in here I guess ill look at it when my BPD calms down thanks though I really do think its just syntax or "grammar" error thanks again!

Comment: There, the `PublishedManager` class is just a handler for the query, very lite can fail here, can you post this class and his assignation to `published`. Did you forget the \? (in the case of spited line)

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information, but if you are trying this,
post = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
Then check the spelling, uppercase,  lowecase in your models.py file.   And also check variable where you mentioned choices_to=.  I assumed that is status.

Comment: I added some code from the models and views files thanks again. I did notice some mispelling errors but I haven't checked if that fixed will after posting this though.

Comment: OK for those of you who helped me out, thanks a lot. I finally found that I had just misspelled a few things and either I didn't get the directory structure right or, I haven't checked yet but, maybe the "installed directory" area had to be placed but it eventually worked. Thanks again!!